# "Finally I can pass my painful moment, thanks mother for always accompanying me in anything happens"

Tags: sentence-construction

If someone says

> Finally I can pass my painful moment, thanks mother for always accompanying me in anything happens

is it correct or incorrect?

Comment: *Pass a moment* is rare. It can mean spend time as in "I passed a few happy moments with friends." Even rarer is the meaning of endure, but it's possible. *Accompanying me in* is also fine; *accompanying me through* is another choice. You'll need the relative pronoun *that*: "anything **that** happens." This also needs to be two sentences. Start the second after *moment*.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things to change here.  First, the tense is odd. The verb "can" informs us that you are able to do something, but not that you have done or will do it. From the context of the sentence, it seems like you are actually talking about something that happened or will happen. If it is something that has already happened, consider

> Finally, I was able to get past that painful moment...

Also, it's not clear whether you are just referencing your mother or speaking to her. If you are just referencing her, consider

> Finally I was able to get past that painful moment, thanks to my mother, who always helps me when I need her.

If you are talking to her, instead say something like

> Finally i was able to get past that painful moment. Thanks, mother, for always being there when I need you.